# Periodic timer implemented in cubit giving me error for flutter widget testing

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

I have a timer countdown app. The state of the time is managed by cubit. When my widget gets initialized(In init state), I am starting the timer by calling cubit function and I am disposing it also. Here is my code -

Main Page-

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => TimerCubit(),
      child: const MaterialApp(
        home: MyHomePage(key: ValueKey('test')),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    context.read<TimerCubit>().startCountDown();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    context.read<TimerCubit>().stopCountDown();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<TimerCubit, int>(builder: (context, state) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              state.toString(),
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 50, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Cubit Code-

```
class TimerCubit extends Cubit<int> {
  late Timer _timer;

  TimerCubit() : super(0);

  startCountDown() {
    _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      int time = state + 1;
      emit(time);
    });
  }

  stopCountDown() {
    _timer.cancel();
  }
}
```

For Widget testing -

```
void main() {
  late TimerCubit cubit;

  setUpAll(() {
    cubit = TimerCubit();
  });

  testWidgets('should work', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(
      BlocProvider.value(
        value: cubit,
        child: const MaterialApp(
          home: MyHomePage(),
        ),
      ),
    );

    await tester.pump();

    expect(find.byKey(const ValueKey('test')), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

The problem is if I try to do widget testing for the MyHomePage widget I am getting following errors -

```
Pending timers:
Timer (duration: 0:00:01.000000, periodic: true), created:
#0      new FakeTimer._ (package:fake_async/fake_async.dart:308:62)
#1      FakeAsync._createTimer (package:fake_async/fake_async.dart:252:27)
#2      FakeAsync.run.<anonymous closure> (package:fake_async/fake_async.dart:187:19)
#5      TimerCubit.startCountDown (package:widget_testing/timerCubit.dart:11:20)
#6      _MyHomePageState.initState (package:widget_testing/main.dart:34:32)
#7      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5015:57)
#8      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4853:5)
...     Normal element mounting (275 frames)
#283    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3863:16)
#284    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6435:36)
#285    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6447:32)
...     Normal element mounting (422 frames)
#707    _InheritedProviderScopeElement.mount (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:411:11)
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#714    SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount (package:nested/nested.dart:222:11)
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#721    SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount (package:nested/nested.dart:222:11)
#722    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3863:16)
#723    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3586:20)
#724    RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1195:16)
#725    RenderObjectToWidgetElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1172:5)
#726    RenderObjectToWidgetElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1186:7)
#727    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4604:5)
#728    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2667:19)
#729    AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:1191:19)
#730    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:378:5)
#731    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1175:15)
#732    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1104:9)
#733    AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.pump.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:1057:9)
#736    TestAsyncUtils.guard (package:flutter_test/src/test_async_utils.dart:71:41)
#737    AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.pump (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:1043:27)
#738    WidgetTester.pumpWidget.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:554:22)
#741    TestAsyncUtils.guard (package:flutter_test/src/test_async_utils.dart:71:41)
#742    WidgetTester.pumpWidget (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:551:27)
#743    main.<anonymous closure> (file:///Users/mesindia/Projects/widget_testing/test/widget_test.dart:23:18)
#744    testWidgets.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:171:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
<asynchronous suspension>
(elided 7 frames from dart:async and package:stack_trace)

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by
calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      Element._debugCheckStateIsActiveForAncestorLookup.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4241:9)
#1      Element._debugCheckStateIsActiveForAncestorLookup (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4255:6)
#2      Element.getElementForInheritedWidgetOfExactType (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4286:12)
#3      Provider._inheritedElementOf (package:provider/src/provider.dart:339:38)
#4      Provider.of (package:provider/src/provider.dart:293:30)
#5      ReadContext.read (package:provider/src/provider.dart:649:21)
#6      _MyHomePageState.dispose (package:widget_testing/main.dart:40:13)
#7      StatefulElement.unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5105:11)
#8      _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1917:13)
...370 more
(package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:848:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown running a test:
A Timer is still pending even after the widget tree was disposed.
'package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1299 pos 12: '!timersPending'

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#2      AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding._verifyInvariants (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:1299:12)
#3      TestWidgetsFlutterBinding._runTestBody (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:857:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
(elided 2 frames from class _AssertionError)

The test description was:
  should work
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following message was thrown:
Multiple exceptions (2) were detected during the running of the current test, and at least one was
unexpected.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

I don't understand what is the problem as I am disposing the timer anyway. If I use the timer without any cubit, directly in the widget's state and dispose it I don't get any kind of error, but with cubit the periodic timer gives me error. Can anyone tell what is the problem here? Should I create mock cubit(I avoided this because as you can see there isn't many functions in the cubit, just a periodic timer).

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was doing wrong. I had to save the cubit reference to a variable. like -

```
late TimerCubit _cubit;

@override
void initState() {
  _cubit = context.read<TimerCubit>()..startCountDown();
  super.initState();
}

@override
void dispose() {
  _cubit.stopCountDown();
  super.dispose();
}
```

previously it wasn't successful to call the `stopCountDown()` method in dispose.(I guess it couldn't access the cubit through the tree).